# How to send email for Office 365 using MailKit?

Tags: email, office365, sendmail

I looked at solving this issue in so many ways.  Here I shall discuss what I was able to achieve.  I have successfully connected to my office 365 account and can read from the inbox:

```
 var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(mail, accessTokenModel.access_token);
 await client.ConnectAsync(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
 await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
 await client.Inbox.OpenAsync(folderAccess)
```

On authenticating the client I could then read the inbox successfully:

```
var messages = new List<MimeMessage>();                
var uids = await client.Inbox.SearchAsync(MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.All);

foreach (var uid in uids) { 
    messages.Add(await client.Inbox.GetMessageAsync(uid));
}
```

However, when I try to send an email I get 403 error, below is the code I am using:

```
 var ews = new ExchangeService();
 ews.Credentials = credentials;
 ews.AutodiscoverUrl(<authemail>, RedirectionCallback);
 ews.ImpersonatedUserId =
 new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, <authemail>);
 var email = new EmailMessage(ews);
 email.Subject = "My first test";
 email.From = new EmailAddress(<authemail>);
 email.ToRecipients.Add(new EmailAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "test@gmail.com"));
 email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, "Hey");
 email.Send();
```

When I execute this code I get a 403 error:

```
The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Below are the permissions granted on the App registered in Azure:

[image: Api Permissions granted on App]

Can somebody assist.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is very simple, don't use IMapClient...  The reason being IMAP is only used for accessing the mailbox, for sending emails you need to use SMTP which as of [December 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online) you can't re-enable Basic authentication in your tenant.  However, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDTO9W81P-Y&t=277s) demonstrates how to get access token and use it.  Just use it with a SMTP client:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    var oauth2Smtp = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(mail, accessToken);
    await client.ConnectAsync(host, smtpPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2Smtp);
    await client.SendAsync(message);
}
```